# how to enable to move cursor in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I create UItextView in pragmatically, and when I tap to move cursor in UITextView, it does not worked. But it worked using IB. Do I supposed to set some attributes to UItextView or UIView?

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];

textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textView.editable = YES;
textView.multipleTouchEnabled =YES;

[self.view addSubview:textView];
textView.delegate = self;
```

I found default long tap does not working.

Comment: My guess is that something else in your app (such as a UITapGestureRecognizer) is "eating" the taps. Whatever the reason, this should work, so the problem must be some complication of your app that you haven't mentioned. To convince yourself of that, make a completely clean project (starting with the Single View template) and try it there.

Comment: you code seems to be correct..so,check the entire code again..because this code has to work..

Comment: @json Thanks for your advise, I want to know code has problem.  I will check another view.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with add subView for gesture recognizer inside custom cell.
When I blocked it or move to background it've started to work:

```
contentView.insertSubview(view, atIndex: 0)
```

where view is view with gesture recognizer.